# Catch the mail address if failed

Tags: c#-4.0

I am sending the mail to multiple address using smtp and I want to get the mail address to which got sendig failed.

```
message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com"));
message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("yyy@gmail.co.in"));
message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("zzz@gmail.com")); 
client.Send(message);
```

In the above list, for the first and third mail got sent and for the second one it cannot.
So I want to catch the failed mail address(yyy@gmail.co.in).

Solution pls

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `client.Send()` method you should call every particular sending method in a `try-catch` block and then serve the failure. 
Another option is to rethrow such a exception up and catch it in the `catch`block in the code you've attached:

```
try {
client.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
//do smth with it
}
```

Tell us something more about your `Send()` method and `client` object. That would let us be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy if you are using the c# SmtpClient and can use the SendAsync method

```
//client and MailMessage construction
client.SendCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) => {
     string emailAddress = eventArgs.UserState as String;
     if (eventArgs.Error != null) { 
        //an error occured, you can log the email/error         
     }
     else //the email sent successfully you can log the email/success
};
client.SendAsync(mail, mail.Sender.Address);
```

if you prefer the lambda can be replaced with new SendCompletedEventHandler(methodName);
and have a method like

```
... methodName(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  string emailAddress = eventArgs.UserState as String;
         if (eventArgs.Error != null) { 
            //an error occured, you can log the email/error
         }
         else //the email sent successfully you can log the email/success
}
```